# How to remove white space above a material top tab bar in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm looking for a way to remove the white space circled in red in my react native top tab bar.

[image]

The top tab bar is in a stack navigator which is a bottom tab navigator

```
const BottomTab = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
        style: { height: 55, borderTopWidth: 0, elevation: 0 },
      }}
    >
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Recent" component={RecentStack} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};

const RecentStack = () => {

  return (
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="RecentTabs" component={RecentTopTabBar} />
        <Stack.Screen name="TaskDetails" component={TaskDetails} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const RecentTopTabBar = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator >
      <Tab.Screen name="Ongoing" component={OngoingJobs} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Completed" component={CompletedJobs} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

I have tried to put marginTop as a negative number but that just makes the tab disappear into the white space. The headerShown attribute is false so what could the white space be.

Comment: have you resolved it?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and you've probably found a solution, but have you tried adding screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }} to your 'BottomTab' navigator?

I ran into a similar issue with react-navigation Bottom Tabs Navigator, and that resolved it.

Comment: even with headerShown: false, still getting additional space at top

Answer (score 0):

If this is a (createMaterialTopTabNavigator)
then you should use "screenOptions" Prop:

```
screenOptions={{
        tabBarStyle: {
          paddingTop: 0,
          marginTop: 0
        },
      }}
```

**Note: Use The Prop should be Inside The <StackName.Navigator />**

Example:

```
<TopTabs.Navigator
      initialRouteName='...'
      screenOptions={{
            tabBarStyle: {
              paddingTop: 0,
              marginTop: 0
            },
          }}
    >
      ....Screen's
    </TopTabs.Navigator>
```